# Is there a way to have a conditional preprocessor in c++

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I want to make a conditional preprocessor macro. The thing I want to do is like `DEBUG(LEVEL, MESSAGE)` and I want it to behave like if I wrote:

```
#ifdef(LEVEL)
std::cout<<MESSAGE<<std::endl;
#endif
```

Is there a way to do that in C++?

This is just an extra reading confort I want to give to myself, it is not really important.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
#define LEVEL 100
#if LEVEL == 100   
    std::cout<< "whatever";
#endif
```

you can find a list do directives [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

EDIT: you can also do something like this:

```
#define DEBUG(X,MESSAGE) if(X==100)std::cout<<MESSAGE<<endl;
```

Comment: Even better would be something like `#define DMESSAGE_LEVEL 100`

Comment: @TarickWelling for "meaning"? i mean, are you saying that for some preprocessor behavior or for having a more meaningfully name?

Comment: yes i know i can do that this way. this question is more to satisfy my curiosity. + this method have the inconvinient to be long to write. I am looking for a shorter macro. the idea would be to have something like (not working) `#define DEBUG(X,message) 
 #ifdef(X) std::cout<<message<<std::endl;`

Comment: the idea is to have a *sort of* function that puts the code only if this debug level is defined. I currently use the `#ifdef X std::cout<<"some debug message" << std::endl; #end`, but this is long to write, takes 3 lines and make my code less easy to read

Comment: @laenNoCode ok posted

Answer (score 1):

Good Information on pre-processor instructions can be found **[here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-preprocessors/)** and **[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)**.
I'd personally recommend the second link, as it's *heavily* edited.

Answer to your code snippet:

---

```
enum level
{
    m_00,
    m_01,
    m_02,
};
// Create: Global Instruction 
#define Args(_instruction_,_level_,_output_)\
_instruction_==_level_?printf(_output_):0;

#define Foo 1 // Example

void main( ) 
{
    Args( Foo, level::m_01, "Level has been verified..." ) 
};
```

Obviously you can change this to fit your needs, but the idea is still the same.